Sum of q-Pochhammer symbols
I suppose the following statement holds, but I am stuck in proving it.
Given $z \in (0,1), a,b,x \in \mathbb{N}, b-1 \geq a+1$, it should hold the following:
$$
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} z^{-2x} \prod_{l=1}^a \left( 1 - z^{2l-2x} \right) = \frac{1}{\left( z^{2(a+1)}-1 \right) } \prod_{l=1}^{a+1} \left(1 - z^{2l-2b} \right) 
$$
I tried to calculate this for several values of $a$ and it holds, but I could not show that this is valid for each $a \in \mathbb{N}$.
The problem is strictly related to this:
Sum of ratio of gamma functions
(it differs on the summand, which now is real, so that solution is not applicable).
I wanted to reproduce the solution to the problem above, as the recursivity looks to me somehow similar. To do this, I tried to convert the expression in q-Pochhammer symbols and then work with the q-binomial coefficients, with the hope that an expression similar to the Hockey-stick identity holds for the q-binomial coefficient too. But I got stuck at some point.
Hereby my attempt
Remind that the q-Pochhammer symbol is
$$
(c;q)_k := \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \left(1- cq^j \right) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-c)^j q^{ {j \choose 2 } } \begin{bmatrix} k \\ j \end{bmatrix}_q
$$
where $\begin{bmatrix} k \\ j \end{bmatrix}_q$ is the q-binomial coefficient.
The we have for the expression in the (supposed) statement: LHS
$$
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} z^{-2x} \prod_{l=1}^a \left( 1 - z^{2l-2x} \right) = \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} z^{-2x} \frac{\left(z^{-2x};z^2 \right)_{a+1}}{1-z^{-2x}} =  \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \frac{\left(z^{-2x};z^2 \right)_{a+1}}{z^{2x}-1}
$$
While the RHS looks like:
$$
\frac{1}{\left( z^{2(a+1)}-1 \right) } \prod_{l=1}^{a+1} \left(1 - z^{2l-2b} \right)  = \frac{1}{\left( z^{2(a+1)}-1 \right) } \frac{\left(z^{-2b};z^2 \right)_{a+2}}{1-z^{-2b}}
$$
So we need to show that
$$
 \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \frac{\left(z^{-2x};z^2 \right)_{a+1}}{z^{2x}-1} = \frac{1}{\left( z^{2(a+1)}-1 \right) } \frac{\left(z^{-2b};z^2 \right)_{a+2}}{1-z^{-2b}}
$$
So starting from LHS, introducing the q-binomial coefficient, we have:
$$
\sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \frac{\left(z^{-2x};z^2 \right)_{a+1}}{z^{2x}-1} = \sum_{x=a+1}^{b-1} \sum_{k=0}^{a+1} \frac{ \left(-z^{-2x} \right)^k \left(z^2 \right)^{ {k \choose 2 } }}{z^{2x}-1} \begin{bmatrix} a+1 \\ k \end{bmatrix}_{z^2}
$$
From here I do not know how to proceed, as:

Changing the order of summation I obtain q-digamma functions, which I think is not the right way to proceed.
But above all, I do not know whether a Hockey-stick-identity-like expression holds for q-binomial coefficients, and eventually, how to deal with the multiplicative terms $\left(-z^{-2x} \right)^k$ and $\left(z^2 \right)^{ {k \choose 2 } }$.

Could anybody help me or provide a hint for that?
Thank you in advance.

Can't this just be done by induction on $b$?

Pochhammer has two hs

Thank you for the idea Darij. I will try!

Thank you J.W. Tanner. I will try to update the title and the text.

For an induction proof as suggested in the comments we need to simplify
$$z^{-2b} \prod_{\ell=1}^a (1-z^{2\ell-2b})
+ \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1} \prod_{\ell=1}^{a+1} (1-z^{2\ell-2b}).$$
This is
$$z^{-2b} \frac{1}{1-z^{2(a+1)-2b}}
\prod_{\ell=1}^{a+1} (1-z^{2\ell-2b})
+ \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1} \prod_{\ell=1}^{a+1} (1-z^{2\ell-2b})
\\ = z^{-2b} \frac{1}{1-z^{2(a+1)-2b}}
\prod_{\ell=2}^{a+2} (1-z^{2\ell-2(b+1)})
+ \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1} \prod_{\ell=2}^{a+2} (1-z^{2\ell-2(b+1)}).$$
Now we have
$$\frac{1}{z^{2b}-z^{2(a+1)}} + \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1}
= \frac{z^{2b}-1}
{(z^{2b}-z^{2(a+1)})(z^{2(a+1)}-1)}
\\ = \frac{1-z^{-2b}}
{(1-z^{2(a+1)-2b})(z^{2(a+1)}-1)}
\\ = \frac{1-z^{-2b}}
{(1-z^{2(a+2)-2(b+1)})(z^{2(a+1)}-1)}.$$
The product emerges, giving
$$\frac{1-z^{-2b}}
{(1-z^{2(a+2)-2(b+1)})(z^{2(a+1)}-1)}
\prod_{\ell=2}^{a+2} (1-z^{2\ell-2(b+1)})
\\ = \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1}
\prod_{\ell=1}^{a+1} (1-z^{2\ell-2(b+1)}).$$
This is the claim.
For the base case $b=a+2$ we get on the LHS
$$z^{-2(a+1)} \prod_{\ell=1}^a (1-z^{2\ell-2(a+1)})$$
and on the RHS
$$\frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1}
\prod_{\ell=1}^{a+1} (1-z^{2\ell-2(a+2)})
= \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1}
\prod_{\ell=1}^{a+1} (1-z^{2(\ell-1)-2(a+1)})
\\ = \frac{1}{z^{2(a+1)}-1}
\prod_{\ell=0}^a (1-z^{2\ell-2(a+1)})
= \frac{1-z^{-2(a+1)}}{z^{2(a+1)}-1}
\prod_{\ell=1}^a (1-z^{2\ell-2(a+1)}).$$
This is the same as the LHS.

Thank you Marko! Indeed with induction in b is the proof unequivocal.
